# impact of updating a column value which has index on it?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I'm trying to determine what situations MySQL updates an index. Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  MyIndexedColumn VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  MyNonIndexedColumn VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  INDEX MyNewIndex(MyIndexedColumn)
)
```

Then I sql queries to insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyIndexedColumn, MyNonIndexedColumn) 
VALUES ('MyTestValue', 'MyTestValue');
```

Now, if I run the following statement, which changes the value of column which is indexed

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET   MyIndexedColumn = 'MyNewIndexValue', 
      MyNonIndexedColumn = 'somenewvalu  New Value' 
WHERE ID = 1;
```

I have this kind of queries coming in all the time .Lots of writes(inserts/updates) and very few reads

1. Will this create performance problems?
2. Will this fragment my index and make them unusable?
3. How can I get away with this problem?

Also, will Oracle  be better or can Mysql handle this kind of data?

Comment: is there a fillfactor option like with sql server ?

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM? They will likely behave differently.

Comment: I want to know for innodb and oracle

Comment: So, what is the conclusion of this. Is it affect the performance when using index on dynamic column  ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's `CREATE TABLE` statement has an option that can make operations more efficient in this specific case. That option is [PCTFREE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses007.htm#g1058547).

Even more than in indexes, fragmentation can occur inside the table with frequent updates, because of [row migration](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_chained_rows.html).

Using Oracle, you can avoid this using a proper `PCTFREE` value. Instead with InnoDB, you can just minimize the side effects, using [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) parameter and running periodically an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for reorganizing data.